# Why calloc call might result into memory corruption and malloc works fine

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, malloc, calloc

I was writing a simple count inversion program using merge sort. While allocating the memory at runtime using calloc I got the following error:

```
a.out: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

with this code:

```
int *temp = (int*)calloc(1, sizeof(int) * (l1+l2)) ;
```

while using malloc instead of calloc works fine.On googling I found it a kind of memory corruption issue but didn't get it clearly

Comment: works fine meant that you are able to use `temp` effectively?

Comment: In C++ don't use `calloc`, and in C [don't cast the return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Regarding the issue you're having, since you allocate zero bytes both [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) and [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) are allowed to return either `NULL` or a valid pointer (it's implementation defined). If you get a non-null pointer, all writes to the memory you "allocated" will be out of bounds, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I'm sorry it was 1 not 0

Comment: Changing `calloc(0, sizeof(int) * (l1+l2))` into `calloc(1, sizeof(int) * (l1+l2))` dramatically changes the question — doesn't it?  Why are you doing the multiplication in the call rather than letting `calloc()` do it for you?  It's a minor issue, though.  Given the revised coding, you're trampling out of bounds, somewhere.  The main difference is that `calloc()` zeroes memory by `malloc()` doesn't. You may be suffering from code that spots the zeroes as a null pointer and works differently. Is [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) available for your platform? If so, use it. If not, get a VM.

Comment: hmm...getting it. BTW I wrote that by mistake.sorry for that

Answer (score 3):

```
void* calloc(size_t num, size_t size);
```

This allocates a block `num` elements, each with size given by `size`. Since you pass `0` for `num`, you are asking to allocate a block of with zero elements. That's surely not what you intended and hence, somewhere down the line, you encounter an error.

I'm not sure what you are attempting to do. It looks like you are attempting to allocate an array of `int` with length `l1+l2`. In which case you need to write:

```
int *temp = calloc(l1+l2, sizeof *temp);
```

Note that I am assuming that you are writing C, and have removed the cast of the return value from `calloc`. If you are writing C++ then you would not be calling `calloc` in the first place. You'd be using `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `calloc` invocation doesn't seem very plausible to me. You are allocating *zero* items, each of which is `sizeof(int) * (l1+l2)` bytes in size.

That being said, I'm not sure whether an assertion is actually valid. The [`calloc` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/calloc.html) says:

> ```
> void *calloc(size_t nelem, size_t elsize);
> ```
>
> […]
>
> ```
> RETURN VALUE
> ```
>
> Upon successful completion with both `nelem` and `elsize` non-zero, `calloc()` shall return a pointer
>       to the allocated space. If either `nelem` or `elsize` is 0, then either a null pointer or a unique 
>       pointer value that can be successfully passed to `free()` shall be returned.

I.e. by this description I'd have expected that you get a pointer (possibly a null pointer) back which is not suitable for anything but being passed to `free()`. Maybe it's not actually the `calloc` call itself which fails but rather subsequent code which attempts to do something with the pointer?

Comment: I'm puzzled that you expect a null pointer from `calloc(0, 0)` when the manual you quote explicitly says you _can_ get a non-null pointer back.  The key point is that you cannot access any memory via the pointer that's returned, either because it is a null pointer or because it points to zero bytes of allocated memory.

Comment: By that description, I'd expect "either a null pointer or a unique 
pointer value". In the latter case, writing through it could easily cause heap corruption.

Comment: Oops, my thinking was ahead of my writing: indeed, I meant to write that you *can* get a null pointer back or a pointer which you can successfully pass to `free` (but not dereferencing let along writing through it).